# Dispatching an action doesn't reach its Root Reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux

This is how my root reducer looks:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux'

const initialState = {
    isAuthenticated: false,
    user: {}
}

function test(state=initialState, action) {

    switch(action.type) {
        case 'TEST_DISPATCH' : return { 
            ...state,
            user: action.payload
        }
        default : return state;
    } 
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({test})

export default rootReducer
```

After creating the store with it, I have:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    test: state.test
  }
}
```

And then:

```
const App = withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main))
```

Somewhere inside `Main`, I have an action creator called:
`this.props.registerUser(some_payload)`.

It looks like this:

```
export function registerUser(userData) {

    return {
        type: 'TEST_DISPATCH',
        payload: userData
    }
}
```

When I call it, it gets called but `function test` from the Root Reducer above never subsequently gets called.

Here's my `mapDispatchProps`:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)

}
```

`actions` is an imported file, it looks like this:

```
export function registerUser(userData) {

    return {
        type: 'TEST_DISPATCH',
        payload: userData
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your `mapDispatchToProps()`, you may not actually be `dispatch`ing the action creator?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky yeah i added it to my post.

Comment: I created a working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dcjpdh) and your code seems to be working. As in the `test` reducer is getting hit on dispatch of `registerUser()`. Are you sure are adding your `rootReducer` to your `createStore()`? Are you sure you are importing `actions` that is passed to `bindActionCreators` correctly such as `import * as actions from './some/path/';`?

Comment: That was my bad.. i accidentally passed to the store `() => rootReducer` instead of just `rootReducer`, no idea why. Thanks for pointing it out! (You can post it as an answer and i'll accept it)

Comment: Also, note that you can simplify your `mapDispatch` declaration as an object instead.  See our new docs page at [`connect`: Dispatching Actions with `mapDispatchToProps`](https://react-redux.js.org/docs/using-react-redux/connect-dispatching-actions-with-mapdispatchtoprops) for details.

Comment: @Gambit2007 sounds good, I'll create an answer. Glad to hear it worked out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating your store using `createStore()` make sure you are passing your `rootReducer` as follows:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer
  // ... applyMiddleware(someMiddleware)
);

export default store;
```

If you pass the the `rootReducer` to the first argument of `createStore()` like `() => rootReducer`, the reducer `test` or any other reducers will never be hit as it needs to be a function that **directly** returns the next state tree.

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dcjpdh) in action.

Hopefully that helps!